# Javascript - Find 2 items in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using `find` in Javascript, how can I find 2 items `10` and `18` from the array?

```
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
ages.find(age => age === 10); // works on one item, returns 10
ages.find(age => age === (10 || 18)); // does not return 10 and 18
```

Comment: `age === 10 || age === 18`

Comment: Or did you mean you want the result to contain both items? I assumed you meant either of two.

Comment: yup, both items. I guess filter it is for multiple :)

Comment: Yep, `filter()` is the way to go then. Be aware that if no result is found, you'll get an empty Array instead of `undefined`. So you can check its `.length` to see if it contains any matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create another array that holds the possible ages you are looking for. This is going to be easier to read and maintain than `or` statements.

```js
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
var criteria = [10, 18];

let found = ages.filter(age => criteria.includes(age));
console.log(found);
```

---

As pointed out by @Flavio Ochoa, [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) may not be supported in legacy browsers. If you're worried about support, or are not using a polyfill for `Array.includes`, you can just use `Array.indexOf` instead:

```
ages.filter(age => criteria.indexOf(age) > -1);
```

Comment: I agree, this is the cleanest approach without `or` statements :)

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) `This is an experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 2016 (ES7) proposal.
Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future version of browsers as the spec changes.`

Comment: @FlavioOchoa, thanks for bringing that to attention. I went ahead and referenced your point, as it is important for future readers.

Comment: @KevBot How fast is that? It would iterate the whole ages array once, then at worst the whole critera array for every ages items to find the corresponding age.

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the `filter` method which returns the elements which matches the predicate.The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The `find` method returns the first element in the array that satisfies the condition. So, using `find`, you wouldn't be able to return more than 1 element.

Also, the comparison is wrong in your code,
**instead of** `age === (10 || 18)`
 *use* `age === 10 || age === 18)`

```js
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
var result = ages.filter(age => age === 10 || age === 18);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
age === (10 || 18)
```

is wrong (it checks only `age === 10`), you need

```
age === 10 || age === 18
```

for checking, second use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get an array with the result.

```js
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
console.log(ages.filter(age => age === 10 || age === 18));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least not with just one call.

(emphasis mine)

> The find() method returns a value of the **first** element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

A better way of approaching this would be to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var ages = [3, 10, 18, 20];
console.log(ages.filter(age => age === 10 || age === 18));
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answers are fine, but they are slow if the arrays are big.

If you only need to find the first 2 items that match, you can use this solution:

```
let a = null, b = null;
for (let age of ages) {
  if (age === 10) {
    a = age
  }
  else if(age === 18){
    b = age
  }

  if(a != null && b != null){
    break;
  }
}
```

In the worst case, it will iterate the ages array entirely once.